# How to add date into nivo stream chart?

Tags: nivo-react

I use [@nivo/stream](https://nivo.rocks/stream/), but at the bottom there is no way to display the date or other information on the chart like here
[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tBw1.png)
but nivo [lets me do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wcz4.png) nivo returns indexes(

Has anyone encountered this and knows a solution to the problem?